# Astrophysicists and Astronomers

Tags: astrophysics, terminology, astronomy

What's the difference between an astrophysicist and an astronomer? Do these two disciplines intertwine or are they the same since they're so synonymous with one another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary focus of astronomy is the collection of observational data, and its reduction into useful information. This includes inventing new data collection tools (mostly telescopes of various types), building them, and managing their operation on earth or in space.

The primary focus of astrophysics is to make sense of observational signals by discovering the underlying physical mechanisms responsible for them. This works in another way: Knowing what those mechanisms are and what sort of signals they will generate, the astrophysicists can predict where and under what circumstances those specific signals can be found, and thereby guide the research efforts of the astronomy community.

Answer (score 0):

Astronomer includes both astrophysicists and astrometrists. The last ones do not deal with physical processes, but rather with the motion of celestial objects and how to to make these predictions precise. They make precise catalogs, etc. For a better description of what they do just search the term.